# pandas dataframe optimized query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a rather large dataframe with upward of 100,000 records. I need to repeatedly perform a range search on a numeric field of this dataframe. I am able to perform this search using loc or query but this is taking lot of time. I think the reason is that right now it is a brute force search. is there someway to generate an index on this numeric field so that I can have a better optimized ranged search on this field.

sample dataframe -

```
field1   field2   field3
red        car     1000000000
green      truck   2000000000
yellow     bus     3000000000
white      bike    4000000000
black      cycle   5000000000
```

search -

```
dataframe.query(field3 > 1000000000 & field3 < 5000000000)
```

I am using this query in a for loop which runs around 6000 times. My overall code is taking around 25 mins. From 150 ms, calling this piece 6000 times will be 900 seconds i.e. 15 mins. If I can somehow create a index on this field then I think the query time would be reduced drastically.

Comment: Do queries always select intervals or is this just an example?

Comment: Did you try sort it first and then query it?

Comment: Can you clarify what a "long time" is? 100,000 records is a fairly small dataframe, I'm getting results of around 150ms per query on a 500,000 record version of your dataframe.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko , I am using the same query again and again in a for loop. its always a select intervals query.

Comment: @HarvIpan I thought of sorting it first but then how does query know to make use of sorting? it will still go through all the records and performance will be same unless I can create some sort of secondary index on this field. right?

Comment: @chrisz I am using this query in a for loop which runs around 6000 times. My overall code is taking around 25 mins. From 150 ms, calling this piece 6000 times will be 900 seconds i.e. 15 mins. If I can somehow create a index on this field then I think the query time would be reduced drastically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to sort the numeric column, then use searchsorted + iloc. E.g.

`df.iloc[df.field3.searchsorted(min_v, 'left'):df.field3.searchsorted(max_v, 'right')]`

This seems to be about 8 times as fast as `df.query` on my machine with 100k records.

If you know the set of your queries ahead of time, you can do better. For example, say you have arrays `mins` and `maxs` with `len(mins) == len(maxs) == 6000`. You can pre-compute

```
min_ix = df.field3.searchsorted(mins, 'left')
max_ix = df.field3.searchsorted(maxs, 'right')
```

And iterate over filtered frames via

```
for i, j in zip(min_ix, max_ix):
    print(df.iloc[i:j])
```